# Unable to navigate to the SFTP directory via python paramiko

Tags: python, python-3.x, sftp, paramiko

```
host = "s-91224f0ccda845345saasdfsd.servers.transfer.in-easte-2.test.com"
port = 22
transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
username = "user1"
mykey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("C:\\Users\\new_pem_file.pem", password="Password@1234")
print("Connecting...")
transport.connect(username = username, pkey = mykey)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
print("Connected.")
print(sftp.listdir())
print(sftp.getcwd())
sftp.put("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\sFTP_Credentials\\TT.xlsx","/")
```

> Blockquote I'm trying to connect to my server and getting the directories details. Then I am uploading a file from my local server to SFTP server. But the issue is I could not navigate to the root directory. If I use sft.listdir(), I am getting only the folder names then when I use sftp.put() to move the file from local dir to server. I am getting error like "Directory Not found".

Note: sftp.getcwd() - I am getting as None. Please someone let me know what am I missing.

Comment: Yes. the output of sftp.listdir() gets me the directory names as ["TEST" ,"TEST2", "TEST3"]. Then when I use sftp.getcwd() to get the current working directory I am getting the output as "None". So I just checked whether I can change the directory to TEST2 like sftp.chdir("TEST2") it throws error as directory not found.

Comment: I even tried sftp.put("Current Directory", "Server directory path") no error is thrown but files are not moved to the server.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I am new to the stackoverflow. But thanks for the reply @MartinPrikryl. I have fixed the issue. The solution is in sftp.put("test.xlsx", "/TEST/test.xlsx") I missed the file name in the remote server path.